# mysqli create link based on row

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, row

I want to create an link based on row value, AND - MORE IMPORTANT, add an variable - if row empty, then this text... if row have some value, display this....

//I NEED TO GET THIS DISPLAY:

// if row season is empty, the resulting link must be

// web.com/MOVIES/".$row["title_id"]."

// if row season have some value, then the link must be:    //web.com/SERIES/".$row["title_id"]."/SEASON/".$row["season"]."/EPISODE/".$row["episode"]."

This is the base code.

```
        <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "dbname";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "SELECT id, type, label, title_id, season, episode, approved FROM links order by id desc LIMIT 30 OFFSET 50";
    $result = $last_id = $conn->query($sql);


    if ($result->num_rows > 0)
     {
        echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Label</th><th>URL</th><th>Season</th><th>Episode</th><th>Approved</th></tr>";
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<tr><td>".$row["id"]."</td><td>".$row["label"]."</td>";
// --------------------------------------------------------------
            echo "<td><a href='http://web.com/(VARIABLES HERE)'>";
            echo " ".$row["title_id"]."</a></td>";
// --------------------------------------------------------------
    //I NEED TO GET THIS DISPLAY:
    // if row season is empty, the resulting link must be
    // web.com/MOVIES/".$row["title_id"]."
    // if row season have some value, then the link must be:
  //web.com/SERIES/".$row["title_id"]."/SEASON/".$row["season"]."/EPISODE/".$row["episode"]."
    // -----------------------------------------
            echo "<td>".$row["season"]."</td><td>".$row["episode"]."</td><td>".$row["approved"]."</td></tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    $conn->close();
    ?>
```

Comment: *"This is the base code."* - and the problem/question is?

Comment: btw, you're using a [reserved MySQL keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) and [you're not seeing the syntax ***error*** it's throwing you.](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

Comment: [Use a ***ternary*** operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), just to answer the question that looks to me, embedded inside your code. Good thing I spotted that, *eh?*

Comment: The problem is in the base code:
    //I NEED TO GET THIS DISPLAY:
    // if row season is empty, the resulting link must be
    // web.com/MOVIES/".$row["title_id"]."
    // if row season have some value, then the link must be:
  //web.com/SERIES/".$row["title_id"]."/SEASON/".$row["season"]."/EPISODE/".$row["episode"]."

Comment: that ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ belongs in your question and not embedded in code, nor in comments.

Comment: pay attention to the comments left and visit those links

Comment: *Giving me poor head a shake*. Time for some *Little Jimmy Pea*.

Comment: Is the column nullable

Comment: is_null() vs. empty():  https://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/php-isset-vs-empty-vs-is_null/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is stated in the comments, you are using a reserved MySQL keyword: `type`.  So your query is not working properly.  You can't tell because you haven't set up any checks to make sure it is working.  you can either put backticks around it like so:

```
SELECT id, `type`
```

*or* **change the name of the key in your database** (I'd recommend this approach, something like titleType).  Until you fix this, nothing will work in your PHP.

Once you have fixed this, as for how to generate your results, you could do something like this inside your while loop  (I'm assuming your mean the episode value):

```
if (empty($row['episode'])) {
     echo 'web.com/MOVIES/'.$row["title_id"];
}
else {
     echo 'web.com/SERIES/'.$row['title_id'].'/SEASON/'.$row['season'].'/EPISODE/'.$row["episode"];
}
```

Comment: `if (empty($row['episode']) {` missing a bracket. Personally, I'd opt for a ternary ;-)

Comment: Many thanhs nomistic and Fred -ii- , this solve my problem.

Comment: @aladin2222 glad to hear it.  if it did, please mark the answer as solved

Answer (score 0):

THIS IS THE CORRECT FULL CODE.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "WRITE YOUR DB username ";
$password = "WRITE YOUR DB password";
$dbname = "WRITE YOUR db name";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT id, label, title_id, season, episode, approved FROM links order by id desc LIMIT 30 OFFSET 1";
$result = $last_id = $conn->query($sql);


if ($result->num_rows > 0)
 {
    echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Audio</th><th>URL</th><th>Temporada</th><th>Episodio</th><th>Aprobado</th></tr>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>".$row["id"]."</td><td>".$row["label"]."</td>";
        echo "<td><a href=";
        if (empty($row['episode'])) {
     echo '/peliculas-online/'.$row["title_id"];
    }
    else {
     echo '/series-online/'.$row['title_id'].'/seasons/'.$row['season'].'/episodes/'.$row["episode"];
        }
        echo ">".$row["title_id"]."</a></td>";
        echo "<td>".$row["season"]."</td><td>".$row["episode"]."</td><td>".$row["approved"]."</td></tr>";

    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```